# Is it okay to hardcode the password of my keystore in my app?

Tags: java, android, ssl, httpclient, keystore

I'm a complete novice when it comes to SSL and security in general. I found the following example on how to load a keystore for trusting custom SSL certificates (this is using Apache HTTPClient, btw):

```
private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
  try {
    KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mystore);
    try {
      trusted.load(in, "ez24get".toCharArray());
    } finally {
      in.close();
    }
    return new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
  }
}
```

I guess you'd need access to the device in order to modify the keystore, but still... isn't there a problem with the fact that the keystore password ("ez24get") is readily available in the code? What would it take to compromise an application containing this code?

Comment: I'd say it smells, but I'm not an Android developer. What other choices do you have to store it? Can it be hashed?

Comment: I dunno. I'm trying to think of ways that I could get the password into the app without storing it somewhere. If I package it encrypted, well, then I'd need the key to be present in the code, so same problem. Android doesn't have built-in hardware-based encryption like BlackBerry does. If I download it the first time the app is started, I need some way of verifying that it really is my app requesting the password, and not someone else. Usually that sort of thing is done with SSL, which I can't use if I can't access the keystore. :-P Man, I don't know how anyone ever figures this stuff out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a risk you are willing to take.

Anyone with enough determination to decompile your code could get it.  Even if you obfuscate your code, you still run the risk since all they need to do is find the string.

Comment: Right. Then once they do that, they'd have to gain root access to a user's device (which would probably require physical access as well), insert their own bogus certificate in the keystore, return the device to the user without them knowing about it, and finally intercept their connection while they're using my app. It would be a pretty big PITA, so it's secure enough for most purposes. But still not completely secure. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Also, I guess I could store the MD5 of the keystore file and check it every time the app starts up to make sure no one messed with it. Then to compromise the app they'd have to edit the class files too.